# Jquery Dialog does not show content on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have tried all the possible ideas to get rid of the problem, I know its a known issue, but how do I get past it, basically jQuery ui does not show the dialog when called twice, using

```
self.$popup.dialog("open");
```

I am using jQuery Ui 1.8.9 and jQuery 1.4.4

Here's my code:

```
   self.$popup = $("#import_box_dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Import Albums',
        modal: true,
        position: "top",
        height: 600,
        maxWidth: 800 ,
        minWidth: 400 ,
        show:"slide",
        width :700,
        "buttons": [
            {
                text: "Import",
                click: self.doImport
            }
        ]
    });
```

Another queer thing i saw was that the dialog box content gets embedded in the outer DOM element.

My dialog DOM structure is like : import_box->

```
<div class="media_import_box" >
    <div id="import_box_dialog">
        <ul id="media_content"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and when when it is displayed second time the DOM tree looks like this

[image: Bug DOM Tree]

The "import_box_dialog" actually moves out of the "import_box" div and I have no idea how it happens, but the display property is none, which does not change when i call the dialog again.

Comment: the dialog is on `#import_box_dialog` but your example uses `#mydialogdiv`, are you sure you're selecting the correct element?

Comment: yes, i am using  self.$popup.dialog("open"); to display the dialog, it opens the first time but the second time does not open up.

Comment: are you creating  `#import_box_dialog`?, if so, are you sure you're not creating more than one?

Comment: updated the question with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue, the issue was that the program was repeatedly creating unnecessary div's whenever `$("import_box_dialog").dialog()` was called. And since the $ operator returns u all the div's matching a given condition, i.e. ID in this case, hence the content did not become visible, which i think made it confused, there are two ways to solve it:

- Remove the Div manually by calling `$("import_box_dialog").child().remove()` This would however remove all the other Div's inside the dialog div
- Use a variable to track the div used for the dialog box, since I am using jquery classes, I use it for the static variable. Thus this way, it tracks the dialog, and always creates the dialog on the same div.

I suppose jquery applies a lot of class styles, due to which  there is ambiguity in the selection of the proper div, and I guess using a static variable solves it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog'
        });

    $('#opener').click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Basic usage of the jQuery UI dialog](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/)

Comment: Hi I am also doing the same thing that you are doing, i do not know why it is not showing, i have tried turning off slide effects, destroyed and re-initialized the dialog everytime it gets called, still no solution,

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all...the OP is using dialog in a more complicated way already, and the issue is unrelated to this example.